# How to use .a library file in arm keil

Tags: arm, stm32, keil, .a

Now I am using the stm32F103 chip, using a .a library file in the keil environment, the compilation is no problem, but the MCU cannot run as soon as I run it

Answer (score 0):

The problem may not be about .a file. Before uploading, check if "reset after flash" option in the debug section.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have confirmed that this option has been selected. As long as I compile the .a file into the project, the mcu cannot run, even if I don't call the function in the .a, and the .a file is not compiled in the project, the mcu can run normally

Comment: What you described is UB( undefined behaviour ), countlessly rooted reasons may cause UB. make sure in the debug mode if MCU is stuck in somewhere or gives any fault.